# How to fix [!] No podspec found for sms_maintained in .symlinks/plugins/sms_maintained/ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I develop multi platform app.

I know that this plugin only works in Android.

But, when I run my app in iOS, it give me error.

plugin that i used : https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained

Process that i've tried :

1. add plugin to `pubspec.yaml`
2. do "`flutter packages upgrade`"
3. do "`pub get`"
4. go to ios directory and do "`pod install`"
5. flutter run (on iOS)

Result from pod install :

> error message : [!] No podspec found for sms_maintained in
>   .symlinks/plugins/sms_maintained/ios

Comment: The issue appears to have been reported to the developer, have you been able to replicate the issue with a blank project ?https://github.com/geordyvcErasmus/flutter_sms/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised that there is a claim someone made it work on iOS!!!

The fine print says that this library is only available for Android!!!

Apple will not let any app, aside from the native messaging app to send out messages.
They are too serious about spam.

Answer (score -3):

i've fixed this issue by modifying sms_maintained in my ios folder

Comment: Modified it to what?

Comment: i forgot the detail. 
But, update the SMSPlugin.m and SMSPlugin.h in Pods. 
change the "methodChannelWithName" to @"sms_maintained"
then try to do pod install